# cant create/add new Virtual Machine on Azure Portal error on resources

Tags: azure

I am receiving this error from the Virtual Machine page creation

> "{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template
>   deployment failed with error: 'The resource with id:
>   '/subscriptions/32cc2407-71f3-4d35-9c3b-d3a2573f18ec/resourceGroups/clt/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm'
>   failed validation with message: 'The requested size for resource
>   '/subscriptions/32cc2407-71f3-4d35-9c3b-d3a2573f18ec/resourceGroups/clt/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm'
>   is currently not available in location 'southeastasia' zones '' for
>   subscription '32cc2407-71f3-4d35-9c3b-d3a2573f18ec'. Please try
>   another size or deploy to a different location or zones. See
>   https://aka.ms/azureskunotavailable for details.'.'."}"

I would accept any help that anyone can suggest

Comment: NB: It seems that if you're using a non-standard subscription (e.g. your Azure instance is related to your VS Pro/Enterprise subscription instead of being a commercially purchased one) some sizes are restricted: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33ee6378-f630-46e8-9327-17ba2009051c/why-are-certain-virtual-machines-sizes-restricted-for-a-subscription?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows.  Sadly even using the `--subscription` parameter with [Greg's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1006640/137255) doesn't seem to help here though.

Comment: NB: I had a similar issue on my Visual Studio Professional subscription.  The reason turned out to be because I was trying to use "Spot Instances".  Per the screenshot here - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55435#issuecomment-633854345 - that feature's not available on a Benefits subscription.

Answer (score 2):

The error message has told you exactly the problem you’re experiencing.

You will need to update your template to specify a size that is available in the region you have chosen.

Using the Azure cli you can run the following:

```
az vm list-sizes --location "southeastasia"
```

This will list the VM sizes available in the location you specify.

See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-list-sizes for specifics.

Answer (score 0):

As per provided log, The VM size which you were selected to deploy,is not available in location "'southeastasia' zones", Check with another VM size.

If its free trial account check the limitation of vCpu core.